# Tfs build cannot find Dnx Runtime for Asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, tfsbuild, dnx

When trying to build an Asp.net application the error

> Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final in the folder:
>   C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService.dnx\runtimes

When I log on to our TFS build server to install the required dnx version using

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1
```

it's installed in C:\Users\myusername.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2.

Our Tfs build process is run with a domain account.

1. How can I install the Dnx runtime in a more generic location?
2. Why is the build process looking for the runtime from that location (NetworkService)?

Comment: Are you using ASPNET 5? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/resolving-Asp-Net-5-dnvm-upgrade-issue-and-changing-dnx-vers/

Comment: I'm using Asp.Net Core, which is the new name for asp.net 5.

Comment: @MathiasR How do you create the Asp.Net Core project? Asp.Net Core does not use dnx anymore. It uses .NET CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to  install Visual Studio to get the required targets.

Right now the DNX MSBuild targets are only installed with Visual Studio 2015 (specifically the Web Development Tools component).

Take a look at this blog which may help you: [Is DNX compatible with MSBuild already?](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2207)

Comment: I have the target files. The problem is that dnx is installed in another folder from where the target is looking for it.

Comment: This may not be the really solution. You could use this workaround [Migrating from DNX to .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migrating-from-dnx) DNX is a little out of date. As of v1, the .NET Core CLI tools don't have an install command for installing dependencies. In order to install a package from NuGet, you would need to add it as a dependency to your project.json file and then run dotnet restore.  Installation: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current Then you just need to add a nuget package restore in your build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is using "1.0.0-rc1-final" but the version installed with "`dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1`" command is 1.0.0-rc1-update2. So you need to run this command to install the final version:

```
dnvm install 1.0.0.-rc1-final
```

After this, you can run `dnvm list` command to check what version has been installed on your machine. And then you need to use `dnvm use` to choose the version. For example:

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -r clr -arch x86
```